# multiple-value in single-value context no return func

Tags: go

I have a func in Go that simply writes to a buffer. I have no return type set on the func so I am not sure why I am seeing this error. Here is my code:

```
func Write(buffer *bytes.Buffer, values ...string) {
  for _, val := range values
    _, err := *buffer.WriteString(val)
    if err != nil {
      // print error
    }
  }
  _, err := *buffer.WriteString(" ")
  if err != nil {
    // print error
  }
}
```

It complains at both lines where I have buffer.WriteString. This leads me to believe it has something to do with the return types of the WriteString method on the buffer but I am not experienced enough in Go to know for sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Updated code.

Comment: I believe the error is due to you not handling the return values from `WriteString` - https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteString - you need the `_` to indicate you're not assigning a value or you need to assign to some variable.

Comment: I tried that, and it still complains. I will update my question with the latest version.

Comment: What is the actual complaint?

Comment: multiple-value buffer.WriteString() in single-value context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to dereference pointers to call methods in Go. The `*` operator before `buffer.WriteString` is applied to the returned values. To dereference `buffer` you would need to write `(*buffer).WriteString`, but that's not needed at all:

```
func Write(buffer *bytes.Buffer, values ...string) {
    for _, val := range values {
        _, err := buffer.WriteString(val)
        if err != nil {
            // print error
        }
    }
    _, err := buffer.WriteString(" ")
    if err != nil {
        // print error
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. I didn't know the star only dereferences return values.